# Retrieving related content between two sitefinity modules

Tags: sitefinity

Before I ask my question, i like to make clear what I am trying to achieve.

I have two modules i created in Sitefinity "**Jobs**" and "**CareHomes**". The **CareHomes** module contains fields such as "**Address**" , "**Location**" and several other information that identifies the **CareHome** while the **Jobs** module is meant to allow the client post jobs for **CareHomes**.

I also have a classification field/taxonomy which is also called **carehomes** this taxonomy is just a list of all the CareHomes operated by the client. This taxonomy field is available in both the **CareHomes** module and **Jobs** module

Now this is my problem: I want the to display information from the **CareHomes** module such as "**Address**" "**Location**" in the **Jobs** widget. That is I want a situation where when the client fills the **Jobs** module form and selects for example "Carehome1" in the **carehomes** taxonomy,I want to be able to retrieve the "address" information from the **CareHomes** that also has the same "Carehome1" taxonomy selected.

I know this is a forum with many professionals and my question may come across to some as silly, however I would appreciate if you are nice in answering my question or pointing me to a helpful resource because I am a newbie to Sitefinity and have only just started using it for about a few weeks.

Comment: What version of Sitefinity are you using?

Comment: Since you deleted your other question without giving me a chance to respond to you thinking I insulted you: I didn't bash you. The purpose of this community is high-quality questions to programming problems others might have. I do not consider that question to fall into that (it's too specific to your situation). I give this advice based on this premise, not to make you look bad or poke fun at you. You can choose to ignore my opinion, but I'll tell you it's common advice here and I myself have deleted several of my own questions. It's the nature of the beast. You did get an answer; some don't.

Comment: @JaredFarrishThanks for taking time to respond here.It does show that you mean well. I obviously did not see it that way. I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options, if you're stuck on 6.3 you might want to look at a [dynamic items field control](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/creating-field-control-with-selector-for-dynamic-items) for the Jobs module that allows you to associate a Job to a CareHome. You can create the field using Sitefinity's Visual Studio plugin called Thunder and add it to your Jobs module. [More info here](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/veselin-vasilev-blog/2013/05/29/working-with-related-dynamic-content-items-in-sitefinity). You would then have to use the api to find the associated CareHome information in your Jobs widget. There is boilerplate code to look this stuff up in module builder under Administration -> Module Builder -> {You Module} -> Code Reference, but it can be a pain.

The other option that I haven't used yet but saw in Sitefinity's last webinar is only available in Sitefintiy 7 and its the new Related Data field that is available to all custom content items and most built in content types. So you'd have to do an upgrade but the the api for getting related items appears to be much easier to work with, [information on that is here](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/related-data-custom-field) and the webinar that shows the new features of Sitefinity 7 [is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMQO7gjvCwA)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have been able to sort this out with the help of one of my senior developers